# Is it problematic to control for ethnoracial identity in analyses?

Tags: data, diversity

I am writing a paper and have been asked by all co-authors to control for race and ethnicity in the analyses. I’ve heard mixed reviews on this once staple practice in the field.

Does anyone have citations about this being either problematic or ok in certain circumstances? Or any other schools of thought of how to equitably account for these variables in the analyses? TIA!

Comment: Some additional information about the discipline and the nature of the problem would be useful. Race is a category that the world puts people in for their lifetime. Careful analysis usually does something with, not always. Has their been discussion in the discipline or professional meetings about what to do?

Comment: Question could do with more/better context.

Comment: Equitably accounting (for variables in analysis) will vary from *causal inference* to *causal mechanisms* approach.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified what problem you are concerned about or what aspect of the use of a race variable you think could potentially be "problematic".  You also say that you've heard mixed reviews, but you don't tell us what concerns you've heard.  This precludes us from giving advice in relation to a particular concern.  In any case, you might be interested in this related question on SE.CV (with answers that include some literature on the problem):

- [When is it valid to use race/ethnicity in causal inference?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366301/)